# All the PPA in software center has been removed

Tags: ppa, repository

all my PPAs are gone. thats why i cant install any other updates because the repositories are unavailable.

- what should i do to bring the repositories back?
- what command lines or methods should i use?

thank you.

Comment: What did you do before the PPAs disappeared?

Answer (score 3):

This I assume is after a distribution update? if so this is the default action but they will be still in the "Other Software" tab but marked as disabled. You get to this by the edit menu in the Ubuntu Software Centre and select software sources. And check the PPAs you want to enable.

Reload the sources. Ubuntu automatically updates the version from ie. "maverick" to "natty". If a PPA has not been updated for the new version, you will receive errors when you reload the sources.  For each error go back and change "natty" back to "maverick" (or whichever version you updated from). This is usually safe as the packages generally work form version to version. Reload sources again and the PPA's should re-appear. You can wait a few weeks and try again with the newer version in case the PPA maintainer has updated his PPA.

Comment: Actually, the version substitution is generally done on upgrade.  You just need to reenable the PPAs you want.

Answer (score 1):

All the source files are located at /etc/apt/sources.list.d/. You will need root privileges to edit the ppa files. See if you added ppa are there as a file. If they are located there see if the content of files are commented or not. If they are not in the above location you have to manually add the ppas using `sudo add-apt-repository` command.

Comment: `Error: need a repository as argument`

what does it mean?

Comment: this means you need a repository argument for the command to work e.g. `ppa:mozillateam/firefox-stable`

Answer (score 0):

Use Aptik to save and restore your ppas. This way you'll never lose them again. And make sure your ppa name matches your linux version name. E.g trusty for trusty, natty for natty, etc. Old ppa may not work on newer Ubuntu and viceversa.
First add Aptik ppa to your system: *sudo apt-add-repository -y ppa:teejee2008/ppa*
Then update your sources list: sudo apt-get update
And finally install Aptik: *sudo apt-get install aptik*
For detailed screenshots of how the program works please visit: http://www.tecmint.com/aptik-a-tool-to-backuprestore-your-favourite-ppas-and-apps-in-ubuntu/ . (Sorry for not posting screenshots here, i don't wanna create a page-long comment).

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! I recommend [edit]ing this answer to expand it with specific details about how to do this. (See also [How do I write a good answer?](/help/how-to-answer) for general advice about what sorts of answers are considered most valuable on Ask Ubuntu.)